# Is it possible to detect range errors in C at compile time

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I know that when gcc is compiling files, it often keeps a list of possible values that a variable can hold (which is then used for various optimizations).   I'm wondering if it's possible to create a compile time warning if the value sits, or potentially sits outside of a range.   For example, if you had function `foo(int x)`, where x has to be between 0 and 5, and then you had: `int y=6; foo(y)`, if it is possible to fail at compile time rather than run time.

Comment: How should the compiler know that the parameter of _your_ function `foo` has to be between 0 and 5 ??

Comment: Only for very basic cases such as the one you mentioned with a function that accepts values within a range, and testing to see if any values are explicitly declared outside that range and then passed to the function. Other than that, you're looking at [the Halting Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).

Comment: Add an assertion in the function if you want to check input parameters and write a unit-test.

Comment: The *halting problem* implies that this is not possible, even theoretically (unless your machine has a finite number states, which can be emulated by your "compiler" beforehand).

Comment: I was thinking of something like a macro wrapper with a static_assert, but I want to check if the value can potentially be out of range, and I don't think that static_assert can do that.

Comment: @John Of course it can. It does need a constant value though.

Comment: If looking for a gcc answer, consider adding gcc tag.  I doubt a generic compiler answer exist as this is certainly not a C spec requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  The following generates a difference with GCC compile for 6, vs. 5.

```
#define Jfoo_MIN 0
#define Jfoo_MAX 5

void Jfoo(unsigned x) {
  printf("%u\n", x);
}

void Jfoo_test(void) {
  const unsigned u = 5;
  const unsigned v = 6;
  struct  {
    unsigned x1 :3;
    unsigned x2 :3;
  } foo = {
      // No warning
      u + (7 - Jfoo_MAX),

      // warning: large integer implicitly truncated to unsigned type [-Woverflow]
      v + (7 - Jfoo_MAX),
  };
  (void) foo;
  Jfoo(u);
  Jfoo(v);

  // warning: expression in static assertion is not an integer constant expression [-Wpedantic] 
  _Static_assert(u <= Jfoo_MAX, "Too hot u");

  // warning: expression in static assertion is not an integer constant expression [-Wpedantic] 
  // error: static assertion failed: "Too hot v"
  _Static_assert(v <= Jfoo_MAX, "Too hot v");
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but my gcc (4.9.2) is raising `error: expression in static assertion is not constant` instead of a warning.

Comment: @John Are you using `-Werror`?  (Warnings as errors)

Comment: FYI "GNU C version 5.3.0, GMP version 6.1.0, MPFR version 3.1.4, MPC version 1.0.3" and "GCC_OPTIONS='-std=c11' '-O3' '-g3' '-Wpedantic' '-Wall' '-Wextra' '-Wconversion''